# Java Applet - Drawing Polygons - Reading RGB

Tags: java, eclipse, canvas, rgb, pixel

I am trying to write a Java Applet that has the ability to draw polygons on a canvas. So far so good.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class DrawingLines2 extends Applet implements ItemListener  {
    DrawCanvas canvas; 

    public void init() {
        // Create components and lay out the applet
        canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    ...
    }
}
class DrawCanvas extends Canvas implements ActionListener, MouseListener{
...
}
```

However, I would then like the program to be able to get the current visible canvas and loop through each pixel, collecting its color.

However, it does not appear that there is a method within the Canvas class that lets me get the color of a pixel in the canvas at a specified point (x,y).
Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach might be to use [`Robot#getPixelColor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#getPixelColor(int,%20int)), but you will need to convert the pixel position from the component space to the screen space. This might be rather slow and you could also have issues creating the `Robot` instance due to the tight security restrictions that applets operate under.

Another option might be to create a `BufferedImage` the same size as the `DrawCanvas` and using its `Graphics` context, call `print` on the `DrawCanvas`

Something like...

```
class DrawCanvas extends Canvas implements ActionListener, MouseListener{
    //...

    public Color getRGBAt(int x, int y) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        paint(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
        return new Color(img.getRGB(x, y), true);
    }
```

Now, personally, I'd strongly discourage you from using AWT based components and encourage you to use the Swing API instead, as AWT is rather antiquated and not many developers are using it actively, making it difficult to find support for problems you might have.  I'd also encourage you not to use applets if you can avoid it, while you are learning; they have a bunch of their own issues which just complicate the whole process, without much gain.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BufferedImage, do your drawings on that BufferedImage then copy the content of BufferedImage to the Canvas using drawImage().

Use getData() or getRGB() from BufferedImage to get the pixel color.